# Issues creating many-to-many relationship with payload using mvc 4 VB.net

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, many-to-many

I have the following tables:

[image]

Users have a many-to-many relationship with Rols, but the intermediate table has payload fields and as you can see, the foreign keys and intermediate table doesn't follow the name conventions. I can't change the database because is used for others systems.

I created the following models:

```
<Table("RolsUsers")>
Public Class RolUser
    <Column("System")>
    Public Property SystemID As Integer
    <Column("Rol")>
    Public Property RolID As Integer
    <Column("User")>
    Public Property UserID As Integer
    Public Property Created As Date

    Public Overridable Property Users As ICollection(Of User)
    Public Overridable Property Rols As ICollection(Of Rol)
End Class

Public Class User
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property Name As String

    Public Overridable Property RolsUsers As ICollection(Of RolUser)
End Class

Public Class Rol
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property Name As String

    Public Overridable Property RolsUsers As ICollection(Of RolUser)
End Class
```

Once I call this line:

```
Dim user = db.User.FirstOrDefault(Function(u) u.Name.Equals(username, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
```

I get the user data only, and the overridable property RolsUser is empty (exception). I think the connection between rols and users is not going well. I'm new using mvc for VB, so any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.

Turns out that the join-table model needs a simple overridable property for each model (table) it points to, and the overridable ICOllections go only in the independent-table models:

```
<Table("RolsUsers")>
Public Class RolUser
    <Column("System")>
    Public Property SystemID As Integer
    Public Overridable Property System As System

    <Column("Rol")>
    Public Property RolID As Integer
    Public Overridable Property Rol As Rol

    <Column("User")>
    Public Property UserID As Integer
    Public Overridable Property Users As User

    Public Property Created As Date
End Class

Public Class User
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property Name As String

    Public Overridable Property RolsUsers As ICollection(Of RolUser)
End Class

Public Class Rol
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property Name As String

    Public Overridable Property RolsUsers As ICollection(Of RolUser)
End Class
```

In this way, several properties can be added to the intermediate-table model and a many-to-many relationship is obtained.

The annotations change the name of the columns used in the database tables.